# Which principle is violated here in the logarithmic equation?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I'm a beginner to mathematics and I'm stuck with a calculus exercise. It seems like I violate a principle, but I cannot yet see what I did wrong here. I hope a second look from a 3rd person will help.

The equation I need to solve is:

\begin{equation}
16^{x}+4^{(x+1)}=12
\end{equation}

With as $x=\frac{1}{2}$ as only real solution. I understand that this can be solved with substitution, but I especially want to solve this problem with writing everything in the same base.

Attempt:

\begin{aligned}
&16^{x}+4^{(x+1)}=12 \\
&\left(4^{2}\right)^{x}+4^{(x+1)}=12 \\
&4^{2 \cdot x}+4^{(x+1)}=12 \\
&4^{2 \cdot x}+4^{(x+1)}=4^{\left(\frac{\log (12)}{\log (4)}\right)} \\
&2 \cdot x+x+1=\frac{\log (12)}{\log (4)} \\
&3 \cdot x=\frac{\log (12)}{\log (4)}-1 \\
&x=\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{\log (12)}{\log (4)}-1\right)
\end{aligned}

Could I please get feedback?

Comment: If you get a wrong solution then you can simply go back and substitute your solution in the previous equations. Then you'll quickly find the point where you made an error.

Comment: Now the problem has been identified, you can write the original problem as a quadratic in $y:=4^x$ to solve it.

Comment: Mistakenly claiming that $f(a+b)=f(a)+f(b)$  for some function $f$, is one of the most common errors in basic mathematics.  In your case $f(x)=\log(x)$.  Other common examples are $f(x)=\frac 1x$ and most famously $f(x)=x^n$ - see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freshman%27s_dream.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The step where you go to $2 \cdot x + x + 1 = (\cdots)$ is incorrect, since $\log_4 (a+b) \neq \log_4 a + \log_4 b$ in general.

Answer (score 12):

Other answers showed the error in your  method. Here is a correct method;

$$
\begin{aligned}
&16^{x}+4^{(x+1)}=12 \\
&\left(4^{2}\right)^{x}+4^{(x+1)}=12 \\
&\left(4^{x}\right)^{2}+4\cdot 4^{x}-12=0 \\&y^2 + 4y - 12 = 0,\\
\end{aligned}$$

which is now a quadratic equation with $y:=4^x$. Solving gives either $y=2$ or $y=-6$, so we now have $$4^x = 2 \qquad\mathrm{or}\qquad 4^x=-6.$$ Given that you are looking only for real solutions, we conclude that $4^x=2$ and $$x=\frac{1}{2}.$$

Answer (score 8):

There is a mistake going from the 4th to the 5th line:
$4^a+4^b\neq4^{a+b}$